# How to remove style sheet override and use inline style with css

Tags: css

I have an element with inline styles:

```
<div class="my-dynamic-element" style="width: 400px; position: absolute; left: 800px; top: 400px;"></div>
```

There is a css override:

```
.my-dynamic-element {
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 40px !important;
}
```

Now without change anything of the above, is there a way in css to remove the css overrides and ask the browser to just use the inline styles?

I tried "auto", "unset", "initial" like

```
.my-dynamic-element {
    left: initial !important;
    top: initial !important;
}
```

But none of them work.

Comment: If you are able to edit the `.my-dynamic-element` class, why can't you simply remove it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mention 'without changing anything of the above' but then your attempt ...changes part of the above. So can we change the above code in our solutions or not?

Comment: I am allowed to add another class, but not modifying the existing code.  I actually did `.my-dynamic-element.my-dynamic-element {...`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `!important` keyword in `style` attributes of tags. So you can simply replace the tag's attribute and append importants in it.

```
<div class="my-dynamic-element" style="width: 400px; position: absolute; left: 800px!important; top: 400px!important;"></div>
```

If you can not change the html element or other styles in your code, you can append a new style tag right before your html element and assign values in it.

```
<style>
    .my-dynamic-element{
        left: 800px!important; 
        top: 400px!important;
    }
</style>
<div class="my-dynamic-element" style="width: 400px; position: absolute;"></div>
```